# Sort divs based on text only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="dropzone">
    <div class='kenmerk_path' data-id='301' data-pk-id='26'>
        elektriciteit -> 220 volt
    </div>
    <div class='kenmerk_path' data-id='271' data-pk-id='31'>
        poort -> aantal per ratio van 1/x m²(aantal)
    </div>
    <div class='kenmerk_path' data-id='202' data-pk-id='68'>
        faciliteiten -> aanmeldingsloket
    </div>
    ...
    <div class='kenmerk_path' data-id='149' data-pk-id='47'>
        elektriciteit -> 250/380 volt
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to sort the inner divs, based on the text that is inside of them. 
So using the following method:

```
function orderDropzone(){
    var mylist = $('.dropzone');

    var listitems = mylist.children('div').get();
    listitems.sort(sort_asc);

    $.each(listitems, function(index, item) {
        mylist.append(item);
    });
}
function sort_asc(a, b){
    return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

I sort them, which works the first time.

But than I dynamically add another div at the end of .dropzone, and call the function again but it won't sort the list again.

I add the new division using the following code:

```
function addKenmerk(item){
    var new_kenmerk = "<div class='kenmerk_path' data-id='200'> 
                            aansluiting -> water 
                       </div>";
    $('.dropzone').append(new_kenmerk);
    orderDropzone();
}
```

So, where I expect that the newly added div would be placed first, nothing changes.

Am I doing something wrong, or am I missing something?

Thnx!

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jf69X/1/

Comment: How you want to sort text?? Based on length, based on lexicographical order or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to trim the text in sorting function like this :

```
function orderDropzone(){
    var mylist = $('.dropzone');

    var listitems = mylist.children('div').get();
    listitems.sort(sort_asc);

    $.each(listitems, function(index, item) {
        mylist.append(item);
    });
}
function sort_asc(a, b){
    return ($.trim($(b).text())) < ($.trim($(a).text())) ? 1 : -1;
}
$(function() {
    function addKenmerk(item){
        console.log('test');
    var new_kenmerk = $("<div class='kenmerk_path' data-id='200'> \
                            aansluiting -> water \
                       </div>");
    $('.dropzone').append(new_kenmerk);
    orderDropzone();
    }
    orderDropzone();
    addKenmerk();
});
```

Here is a working jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pnMWZ/

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be correct Javascript. To write a multi-line string, you have to add a backslash (`\`) at the end of each line:

```
var new_kenmerk = "<div class='kenmerk_path' data-id='200'> \
                       aansluiting -> water \
                   </div>";
```

By the way, it's not recommended to use multi-line strings in Javascript, because of people forgetting about white spaces, but it's safe in your case.

Comment: Yes and it should be not string but node.

Comment: I just wrote it that way to make it a little more readable. In my real code, it is correct javascript.

Comment: @setec To be honest, appending raw HTML is a common practice, especially now that functions like `insertAdjacentHTML` are well supported.

Comment: @JasperV Oh well, that tricked me. :) That was the most obvious thing I could find...

Comment: @MaxArt i see, tnx for info. Then it was just a newline break issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new item like here:

http://jsfiddle.net/setec/Z8amc/3/

```
function addKenmerk(item){
    var new_kenmerk = $("<div class='kenmerk_path' data-id='200'> aansluiting -> water  </div>");
    $('.dropzone').append(new_kenmerk);
    orderDropzone();
}
```

Comment: UPD: considering that code in question was edited to make more readable, the original code is working fine.